# Several apps sharing one MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, microservices

I'm building project that has many apps in it *(microservice architecture)* and all of them are sharing one mysql database. Is it possible to grant access to several tables in database? For example, I want that my app1 only has access to one table in database not all of them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can **grant various privileges to various users** in MySQL, and in most database servers such as Postgres, H2, MS SQL Server, and so on.

Create a user for each application. Grant permissions to certain tables for each of those users.

```
GRANT type_of_permission 
ON database_name.table_name 
TO ‘username’@'localhost’ 
;
```

Commonly used permissions include:

- ALL PRIVILEGES (full access to database or entire database server)
- CREATE
- DROP
- DELETE
- INSERT
- SELECT
- UPDATE
- GRANT OPTION (granting/revoking privileges to other users)

See [tutorial at DigitalOcean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql).